# Spark dataset: return a HashMap of values having same key

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

```
+------+-----+
|userID|entID|
+------+-----+
|     0|    5|
|     0|   15|
|     1|    7|
|     1|    3|
|     2|    3|
|     2|    4|
|     2|    5|
|     2|    9|
|     3|   25|
+------+-----+
```

I want the result as {0->(5,15), 1->(7,3),..}

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is your table again:

```
  val df = Seq(
    (0,  5),
    (0, 15),
    (1,  7),
    (1,  3),
    (2,  3),
    (2,  4),
    (2,  5),
    (2,  9),
    (3, 25)
  ).toDF("userId", "entId")
  df.show()
```

Outputs:

```
+------+-----+
|userId|entId|
+------+-----+
|     0|    5|
|     0|   15|
|     1|    7|
|     1|    3|
|     2|    3|
|     2|    4|
|     2|    5|
|     2|    9|
|     3|   25|
+------+-----+
```

Now you can group by `userId` and then collect `endId` to lists, aliasing the resulting column with lists as `entIds`:

```
  import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
  val entIdsForUserId = df.
    groupBy($"userId").                        
    agg(collect_list($"entId").alias("entIds"))

  entIdsForUserId.show()
```

Output:

```
+------+------------+
|userId|      entIds|
+------+------------+
|     1|      [7, 3]|
|     3|        [25]|
|     2|[3, 4, 5, 9]|
|     0|     [5, 15]|
+------+------------+
```

The order after `groupBy` is not specified. Depending on what you want to do with it, you could additionally sort it.

You can collect it into a single map on the master node:

```
  val m = entIdsForUserId.
    map(r => (r.getAs[Int](0), r.getAs[Seq[Int]](1))).
    collect.toMap
```

this will give you:

```
Map(1 -> List(7, 3), 3 -> List(25), 2 -> List(3, 4, 5, 9), 0 -> List(5, 15))
```

Answer (score 2):

One approach would be to convert the Dataset to a RDD and perform a `groupByKey`.  To obtain the result as a `Map`, you'll need to `collect` the grouped RDD provided if the dataset isn't too big:

```
val ds = Seq(
  (0, 5), (0, 15), (1, 7), (1, 3),
  (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5), (2, 9), (3, 25)
).toDF("userID", "entID").as[(Int, Int)]
// ds: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[(Int, Int)] =[userID: int, entID: int]

val map = ds.rdd.groupByKey.collectAsMap
// map: scala.collection.Map[Int,Iterable[Int]] = Map(
//   2 -> CompactBuffer(3, 4, 5, 9), 1 -> CompactBuffer(7, 3),
//   3 -> CompactBuffer(25), 0 -> CompactBuffer(5, 15)
// )
```

Comment: Given that the resulting hash map contains *all* entries of the original DataFrame, my guess was that the OP wanted it as another DataFrame, not as hashmap on the master node, so maybe the version with intermediate `agg`-step turned out to be useful after all... But I've honestly tried to upvote your solution as the shorter one :]

Comment: Thanks @Andrey Tyukin.  I think your intermediary step as an option for retaining data at scale makes good sense.